# ag-grid 'agSetColumnFilter' not working with floating filter

Tags: filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image when - floatingFilter: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Eec.png)

[1] [image when - floatingFilter: true, filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE6Gw.png)

I am trying to integrate floating filter along with 'agSetColumnFilter',these are the scenarios- when setting following values in defaultColDef:
(filter : true, floatingFilter: true) - floating filter is coming in UI but disabled
(filter : 'agSetColumnFilter', floatingFilter: true) - no floating filter in UI
(filter : 'agTextColumnFilter', floatingFilter: true) - working perfectly fine
(filter : 'agMultiColumnFilter', floatingFilter: true) and  (filter: 'agSetColumnFilter') in each coldef - floating filter is coming in UI but disabled

There is a requirement where I want a floating filter along with agSetColumnFilter,(Just like we have in ag-grid Demo for 'Game Name' Column
https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php)
what can be the issue?

Comment: Do you have Enterprise license? Set filter is not available in Community version.

Comment: yes, I have license, using it in App.js ---
import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
    LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("MY_LICENSE_KEY");

Comment: OK. Then edit your question to provide a sample of code when the filter is disabled.